# Is there a way to get Sublime Text 3 to show theme edits without restarting the app?

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3

I am trying to edit a theme in Sublime Text 3. I will be making several changes and I am doing it by editing the .sublime-theme file in the .zip directory located in .config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages. Each time I change a setting I have to restart ST3 to see the results.
Is there a way to do this so that I can see the results right away in the same manner that editing Preferences.sublime-settings does?

Comment: On Windows I don't find I have to restart ST3 to see changes, maybe it's different on Linux. But anyway try [this plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorSchemeEditor) which includes a real time preview.

Comment: ColorSchemeEditor looks like it will be quite useful for editing the color of my code, but I am trying to edit things like the font size of the labels on the tabs for each open file.
I tried unpacking the theme using PackageResourceViewer but it still doesn't seem to update the way that settings changes do.
I'm hoping there's some way to update the cache or something but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question, you're right it does require a restart to see those changes, I don't know of a way round that. As an aside the readme for [https://packagecontrol.io/packages/KCPS%20Theme](this theme) has a helpfully detailed explanation of how to edit a theme.